# appBar back button/update List in other class

Tags: flutter, dart

In my project I move from the current page (2) to the previous one (1) an updated a List, through the constructor, with the back button in the appBar

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement (
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute (
                builder: (context) => new PagesListPage (
                      pagesList: list Pages,
                    )),
          )
```

The data is updated correctly on the previous page
but Flutter rightly 'duplicates' the previous page (1) in the stack, that is:

```
on page 1 - tap on button to go to page 2                            ---> I see page 2
on page 2 - tap on button back in appBar (navigator.pushReplacement) ---> I see page 1
on page 1 - tap on button back in appBar                             ---> I see again page 1
```

How can I eliminate the double occurrence of page 1 in the stack?

Or alternatives to update the List on page 1 from page 2.

I'm starting out with Flutter, and I've also tried with Provider, but if I understand correctly it can only update a 'value', I couldn't get it to update a 'List'!

Thanks for any valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

On page 1 navigator:

```
buttonPressPage1() async {
    var updatedData = await Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page1));
  setState(() {
     oldData = updatedData;
  });

}
```

On page 2 navigator:

```
buttonPressPage2()  {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(updatedData);
}
```

Using await to you can update the data.

Comment: Many thanks Vignesh for your help.
I'm trying to adapt your valuable suggestions to my code.
But as I wrote, going back to page 1, **I already got the updated data**.
The problem was that with pushReplacement I then had **two pages 1** in the navigator (and backpage button of appBar).
Moreover the kind of data I would like to receive back is a List, not just a string.
I really hope your solution works, I've been stuck for days and I'm going crazy!

Comment: All the best..!